# Polymer CoreInput set custom validation message and reverse direction

Tags: polymer

**First**

It looks like it's possible to set custom validation rules, but I'm wondering if there is any way to customize the validation messages (I need them to be in Arabic).

**Second**

Is it possible to reverse the direction of `paper-input` floating label (place it at top right instead of top left).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**

paper-input exposes a `error` attribute you can use to declaratively set a custom message. If you want to use core-input directly, that element exposes a `setCustomValidity(message)` for setting it.

http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-input

**Second**

That would be a good feature request to file against paper-input. I was able to get something working using CSS overriding, but the internals of the API could change in the future.

http://jsbin.com/megafucuvapo/1/edit

Comment: I have a `type=email` validation on my paper-input. When I start typing the built in email validation fires and it works as expected - it shows it's own error message. 
But when I set a custom error message (e.g. "This email is not in the database") via `error` attribute or `setCustomValidity()` the built in email validation can't change this error message anymore. Is it a bug or there is another way of assigning the error message?

Comment: would love to know hot to set a custom error message on paper-input